# set proxy for firefox using sikuli in java

Tags: java, sikuli, browser-automation, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

I'm new to [sikuli](http://sikulix.com/) and I want to run firefox and set proxy on it (through foxyproxy) using sikuli. This code opens firefox and load "https://google.com". How would I click on foxyproxy button in firefox toolbar and create new proxy using sikuli?

```
import org.sikuli.script.*;


public class SikulixTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Screen s = new Screen();
        App browser = App.open("Firefox");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        browser.focus();
        s.highlight(0);
        s.type("https://google.com" + Key.ENTER);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        browser.close();
    }

}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sikuli works based on visual pattern matching. In order to do what you need, you have to:

1. take a screenshot with the area of the screen you want to interact with (in your case the FoxyProxy icon in FF)
2. Define an object of type `Pattern`
3. Used the object defined in step to to find the pattern on the screen

```
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("screenshot.png");
Match m = s.find(pattern);
m.click();
```